# Swift : Hide Labels if Empty

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, label

I'm completely new to Swift development, I'm working on a project that parses a JSON file to a CustomCell inside a UITableView. The problem I'm having is that I have labels that are empty(because of my optional unwrapping)  and I don't want them to display in my cell if empty. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class ScheduleTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!

    var nodeCollection = [Node]()

    var service:NodeService!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        service = NodeService()
        service.getNodes {
            (response) in
            self.loadNodes(response["nodes"] as! NSArray)
        }
    }



    func loadNodes(nodes:NSArray){

        for node in nodes {

            var node = node["node"]! as! NSDictionary

            var field_class_day_value = node["field_class_day_value"] as! String

            var field_class_time_start_value = node["field_class_time_start_value"] as! String

            var field_class_time_end_value = node["field_class_time_end_value"] as! String

            var field_class_flex_header_value = node["field_class_flex_header_value"] as! String

            var title = node["title"] as!String

            var field_ages_value = node["field_ages_value"] as? String

            var field_class_footer_value = node["field_class_footer_value"] as? String

            var field_class_flex_footer_value = node["field_class_flex_footer_value"] as! String

            var field_class_instructor_nid = node["field_class_instructor_nid"] as? String



            if (field_class_day_value == "1"){

                field_class_day_value = "Monday"

            }else if (field_class_day_value == "2"){

                field_class_day_value = "Tuesday"

            }else if (field_class_day_value == "3"){

                field_class_day_value = "Wednesday"

            }else if (field_class_day_value == "4"){

                field_class_day_value = "Thrusday"

            }else if (field_class_day_value == "5"){

                field_class_day_value = "Friday"

            }else if (field_class_day_value == "6"){

                field_class_day_value = "Saturday"

            }else{

                field_class_day_value = "Sunday"

            }


            //convert time
            var dataStringStartTime = field_class_time_start_value
            var dataStringEndTime = field_class_time_end_value

            var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            var dateFormatter2 = NSDateFormatter()

            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "h:mm a"



            let dateValueStartTime = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dataStringStartTime) as NSDate!
            let dateValueEndTime = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dataStringEndTime) as NSDate!

            let class_time_start_value = dateFormatter2.stringFromDate(dateValueStartTime)
            let class_time_end_value = dateFormatter2.stringFromDate(dateValueEndTime)

            let class_time_final = "\(class_time_start_value) - \(class_time_end_value)"

            let title_final = title.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())


            var nodeObj = Node(field_class_day_value: field_class_day_value,


                class_time_final: class_time_final,

                field_class_flex_header_value: field_class_flex_header_value,

                title_final: title_final,

                field_ages_value: field_ages_value,

                field_class_footer_value: field_class_footer_value,

                field_class_flex_footer_value: field_class_flex_footer_value,

                field_class_instructor_nid: field_class_instructor_nid)

            nodeCollection.append(nodeObj)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }

        }

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return nodeCollection.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell : CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        let node = nodeCollection[indexPath.row]
        cell.lbl_day_value.text = node.field_class_day_value
        cell.lbl_class_time_final.text = node.class_time_final
        cell.lbl_flex_header_value.text = node.field_class_flex_header_value
        cell.lbl_title.text = node.title_final
        cell.lbl_ages_value.text = node.field_ages_value
        cell.lbl_footer_value.text = node.field_class_footer_value
        cell.lbl_flex_footer_value.text = node.field_class_flex_footer_value
        cell.lbl_instructor_nid.text = node.field_class_instructor_nid

        return cell
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give this a try:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    let node = nodeCollection[indexPath.row]
    cell.lbl_day_value.text = node.field_class_day_value
    cell.lbl_class_time_final.text = node.class_time_final
    cell.lbl_flex_header_value.text = node.field_class_flex_header_value
    cell.lbl_title.text = node.title_final
    cell.lbl_ages_value.text = node.field_ages_value
    cell.lbl_footer_value.text = node.field_class_footer_value
    cell.lbl_flex_footer_value.text = node.field_class_flex_footer_value
    cell.lbl_instructor_nid.text = node.field_class_instructor_nid

    //Get all your labels and check if they are now empty
    for view in cell.subviews {
        if let label = view as? UILabel {
            if label.text!.isEmpty {
                label.hidden = true
            }
            else {
                label.hidden = false
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Also, just as a standard practice, when you have `elseif`s like that, using a switch looks a lot nicer:

```
switch field_class_day_value {
    case "1":
        field_class_day_value = "Monday"
    case "2":
        field_class_day_value = "Tuesday"
    case "3":
        field_class_day_value = "Wednesday"
    case "4":
        field_class_day_value = "Thrusday"
    case "5":
        field_class_day_value = "Friday"
    case "6":
        field_class_day_value = "Saturday"
    default:
        field_class_day_value = "Sunday"


}
```

Sample Here: https://mega.nz/#!Q1xT3YJR!TP_BOCBVt6mCg1YAafo6EHQKIPqYKzT6scU6ZAPtgWg

Comment: I forgot to set hidden = false for the non empty labels. This is important because of reusing cells.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I would try pinning the top and bottom of the table view cell and subtract the height of the label from the constraint each time you hide a label.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not entirely sure how to do that. I've been trying to get my project up on github.

Comment: @JShuart I can create a sample project real quick to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks Caleb, I was able to finally upload to github...here's my link https://github.com/jshuart/CultureShock-v.15.git

Comment: I added a link to a sample project. I can take a look at your project later, but it might be faster if you adapt my solution to yours since you know your project better than I do.